# Code organizing

Tags: c++, code-organization, visitor-pattern

I have this visitor pattern implementation:

```
class Visitor {
  public:
    Visitor() {}
    void visit(A *a){ a->doSomething(); }
    void visit(B *b){ b->doSomething(); }
};

class Base {
  public:
    Base() {}
    virtual void accept(Visitor *v) = 0;
};

class A: public Base {
  public:
    A():Base() {}
    void accept(Visitor *v) override { v->visit(this) };
    .....
};

class B: public Base {
  public:
    B():Base() {}
    void accept(Visitor *v) override { v->visit(this) };
};
```

The problem is that `A` and `B` have incomplete types in the Visitor implementation. But  I don't want to put implementation in a separate source file.

Is there a way to put it in a single header file?

Comment: "_Is that a way to put it in a single header file?_" Why would you want to put implementation in the header file? If you put implementations into source files - you don't have a problem with "incomplete type".

Comment: Try forward declaration.

Comment: @AlexeyUsachov That, still, won't allow to have implementations of such methods in a header file. The problem that `a`, and `b` has incomplete type hints at the problem being the method call, not the usage of `A`, and `B`. As far as I can see, one, would, ultimately, need to move implementation of _something_, to the source file, and there's no solution of pure header implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do forward declaration `A` and `B`. Move your `visit(A*a);` and `visit(B*b);` outside of Visitor's class declaration and declare it after `A` and `B` classes. To avoid duplicate symbols put this to header file, for example Header.h:

```
//forward declarations
class A;
class B;

class Visitor {
public:
    Visitor() {}
    void visit(A *a);
    void visit(B *b);
};

class Base {
public:
    Base() {}
    virtual void accept(Visitor *v) = 0;
};

class A: public Base {
public:
    A():Base() {}
    void accept(Visitor *v) override { v->visit(this); };
    void doSomething(){};
};

class B: public Base {
public:
    B():Base() {}
    void accept(Visitor *v) override { v->visit(this); };
    void doSomething(){};
};
```

This declaration should be putted in cpp file, to avoid duplicate symbols, for example add it to main.cpp:

```
#include "Header.h"

//outside declarations of methods
void Visitor::visit(A *a){ a->doSomething(); }
void Visitor::visit(B *b){ b->doSomething(); }
```

Comment: What happens, if you include such a file in multiple source files? Don't you get linker errors, once you try to link it to final application?

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius Yes, thanks for your comment, I have added improvements to my answer to avoid possible duplicate errors by linker

Answer (score 0):

**The main point is :**

As long as you have two classes (for instance A and Visitor), and that each one's implementation needs the other one's declaration, you cannot merge implementation and declaration.

In your case :

```
class Visitor {
public:
    // Visitor's implementation needs A's declaration
    void visit(A *a){ a->doSomething(); }
};

class A {
  public:
    // A's implementation needs Visitor's declaration
    void accept(Visitor *v) { v->visit(this) };
    void doSomething() { ... };
};
```

That's one of the reasons you **want** to have declaration and implementation in separated files.
There are plenty of other reasons, including the differential compilation time.

May I ask why you want to implement all of them in the same file ?

**But :**

Depending on what you are trying to achieve, you may want to trick it. But that will be a pain to maintain. **I'll never do that except for a very good and unusual reason**.

For instance, I assume something like that should work :

```
class Doer {
  public:
    // Doer's implementation don't needs Visitor's declaration
    virtual void doSomething()=0;
};

class A;
class Visitor {
public:
    // Visitor's implementation needs Doer's declaration
    void visit(A *a){ ((Doer*)a)->doSomething(); }
};

class A: public Doer {
  public:
    // A's implementation needs Visitor's declaration
    void accept(Visitor *v) { v->visit(this) };
    void doSomething() override { ... };
};
```

Once again, if you have a choice : **don't do that**. Prefer to split your file. This workaround, even well documented, will be very hard to maintain.